# JavaFX8 - ListView cant leave loop

Tags: java

i just wrote a little user management application where you can create Objects of the type "User". This objects will be saved in an ArrayList. Right now i am trying to print the Users via ListView on a gui, but whenever i start my JavaFX8 Application, nothing is showing up until i get an error after like 2-3 mins.

Looks like my while()-Loop isnt working. I also tried to print only one user with the following code and its working, but yea i know why its only printing one user:

```
lv.getItems().add(verwaltung.iterator().next());
```

I tried to print the full ArrayList using the following code, but it doesnt work.. Looks like it doesnt leave the loop.. q.q

```
while(verwaltung.iterator().hasNext()) {
        lv.getItems().add(verwaltung.iterator().next());
    }
```

I appreciate any kind of help.. :)

Thanks in advance!

user_gui.java

```
public class user_gui extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Userverwaltung verwaltung = new Userverwaltung();
    verwaltung.addUser(new User("Brian", 19));
    verwaltung.addUser(new User("Adam", 10));
    verwaltung.addUser(new User("Jenny", 21));
    BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
    ListView lv = new ListView();
    while(verwaltung.iterator().hasNext()) {
        lv.getItems().add(verwaltung.iterator().next());
    }
    System.out.print("Hallo");
    bp.setCenter(lv);
    Scene scene = new Scene(bp);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}

public static void main(String args[]){
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Userverwaltung.java

```
 public class Userverwaltung {

private List<User> userlist = new ArrayList();
private File savefile = new File("users.ser");
private static int counter;

public Userverwaltung(){
    counter++;
}

public void addUser(User user){
    userlist.add(user);
}

public void printUsers(){
    Iterator<User> it = userlist.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        it.next().printData();
    }
}

public void saveObjects(){
    try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(savefile);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);) {
        oos.writeObject(userlist);
    }catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void loadObjects(){
    try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(savefile);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);) {
        this.userlist = (ArrayList) ois.readObject();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Iterator<User> iterator(){
    Iterator<User> it = userlist.iterator();
    return it;
}
}
```

User.java

```
public class User implements Serializable {

private String name;
private int age;

public User(String name, int age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public int getAge(){
    return age;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public void setAge(int age){
    this.age = age;
}

public void printData(){
    System.out.println("Name: " + getName() + " - Alter: " + getAge());
}

public String toString(){
    return "Name: " + getName() + " - Alter: " + getAge();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(verwaltung.iterator().hasNext()) {
    lv.getItems().add(verwaltung.iterator().next());
}
```

You are creating a new Iterator with every iteration of your while loop.
So every time your loop checks its condition, you allways get a new Iterator and start from  the beginning (never reaching the end of your verwaltung list)

Try to change it to

```
Iterator iterator = verwaltung.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    lv.getItems().add(iterator.next());
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your help, its working now! :)

Comment: No Problem. If the Answer solved your Problem then please accept it as an answer. (see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :)

Comment: Ye i had to wait 3 mins.. but there we go :)